# Is there any workaround to play videos with TestCafe (Chrome) without adding the &quot;chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required&quot; flag

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe, testcase, end-to-end

I have this video that plays automatically when I manually interact with the page. 
When running TestCafe the page freezes and the video does not play even if I click the play button.

Adding the `chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` flag solves the problem but I am not required to add that flag. Is there any way I can initiate a user gesture in TestCafe? Or bypass this requirement without adding the tag?

Answer (score 0):

The '--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required' flag is required to run tests in Google Chrome with test pages on which there are playing sounds or videos.

There is an suggestion in the repository connected with TestCafe to add this flag to flags used for Google Chrome running - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-tools/issues/156.